# Connection issue with vsftpd and ProFTPD from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ftp, vsftpd, proftpd

I have one server, Linux based, I use for some years like a backup cloud server. This work very well with client like *Windows 7*, *Ubuntu* and *Android*. But Not with *Windows 10*.

All programs I have used for connections worked well without problems for years with these clients.

Now I would like to connect another computer for online backup with *SyncBackFree* or *freefilesync* on the Windows 10 Operating System and I have some problems with FTP connections.

To do a test, I also tried the FTP connection with FileZilla and even here, with Windows 10, I find the same problem.

The program I use as FTP server is `vsftpd`, but I have also tried `ProFTPD`, showing the same problem.

Here's some test:

The FTP server on a Linux system with ProFTPD (with vsftpd it is a very similar result)

----------------Test connection 1:

```
client SyncBackFree on Windows 10 32bit  

13/01/2019 03:48:33: SyncBackFree V8.5.97.0  
13/01/2019 03:48:33: Windows 10 build 17134  
13/01/2019 03:48:33: Resolving host name "82..."  
13/01/2019 03:48:33: Connecting to 82... Port: 25  
13/01/2019 03:48:33: Connected to 82...**.  
13/01/2019 03:48:34: 220 ProFTPD 1.3.5a Server (MaxServerFtp) [192.168.1.8]  
13/01/2019 03:48:34: USER odroid  
13/01/2019 03:48:34: 331 Password required for odroid  
13/01/2019 03:48:34: PASS (hidden)  
13/01/2019 03:48:35: 230 User odroid logged in  
13/01/2019 03:48:35: SYST  
13/01/2019 03:48:35: 215 UNIX Type: L8  
13/01/2019 03:48:35: Detected Server Type: UNIX  
13/01/2019 03:48:35: RTT: 26.404 ms 13/01/2019 03:48:35: FEAT  
13/01/2019 03:48:35: 211-Features:  
13/01/2019 03:48:35: SITE MKDIR  
13/01/2019 03:49:36: Timeout (60s).  
13/01/2019 03:49:36: 3  
13/01/2019 03:49:36: Client closed the connection.
```

---------------Test connection 2:

```
freefilesync on Windows 10 32bit  

CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT: server response timeout  
SITE MKDIR [curl_easy_perform]
```

---------------Test connection 3:

```
filezilla client on Windows 10 32bit  

Stato: Connessione a 82...:25...  
Stato: Connessione stabilita, in attesa del messaggio di benvenuto...  
Stato: Server non sicuro, non supporta FTP su TLS.  
Comando: USER odroid  
Risposta: 331 Password required for odroid  
Comando: PASS **************  
Risposta: 230 User odroid logged in  
Comando: SYST  
Risposta: 215 UNIX Type: L8  
Comando: FEAT  
Risposta: 211-Features:  
Risposta: SITE MKDIR  
Errore: Timeout connessione dopo 20 secondi di inattività  
Errore: Impossibile collegarsi al server  
Stato: In attesa di un nuovo tentativo...  
Stato: Connessione a 82...:25...  
Stato: Connessione stabilita, in attesa del messaggio di benvenuto...  
Risposta: 220 ProFTPD 1.3.5a Server (MaxServerFtp) [192.168.1.8]  
Comando: AUTH TLS  
Risposta: 500 AUTH not understood  
Comando: AUTH SSL  
Risposta: 500 AUTH not understood  
Stato: Server non sicuro, non supporta FTP su TLS.  
Comando: USER odroid  
Risposta: 331 Password required for odroid  
Comando: PASS **************  
Risposta: 230 User odroid logged in  
Comando: FEAT  
Risposta: 211-Features:  
Risposta: SITE MKDIR  
Errore: Tentativo di connessione interrotto dall'utente
```

Here is the log example of a successful connection from a Windows 7 client to a ProFTPD server on Linux:

```
Connecting to 82..., Port 25  
220 ProFTPD 1.3.5a Server (MaxServerFtp) [192.168.1.8]  
USER odroid  
331 Password required for odroid  
PASS (hidden)  
230 User odroid logged in  
FEAT  
211-Features:  
SITE MKDIR  
MFF modify;UNIX.group;UNIX.mode;  
REST STREAM  
MLST modify*;perm*;size*;type*;unique*;UNIX.group*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.owner*;  
UTF8  
EPRT  
SITE SYMLINK  
EPSV  
SITE UTIME  
LANG it-IT.UTF-8;it-IT;en-US.UTF-8;en-US*  
MDTM  
SITE RMDIR  
TVFS  
SITE COPY  
MFMT  
SIZE  
211 End  
OPTS UTF8 ON  
200 UTF8 set to on  
REST 0  
350 Restarting at 0. Send STORE or RETRIEVE to initiate transfer  
PWD  
257 "/home/odroid" is the current directory  
CWD /var/www/test/htdocs  
250 CWD command successful   
TYPE A  
200 Type set to A  
PASV  
227 Entering Passive Mode (82...,156,201).  
MLSD  
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for MLSD  
226 Transfer complete
```

Can someone help me?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you very much zx485! very appreciated intervention